# Ubuntu treats /home as separate folders

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have just finished a fresh installation of Ubuntu Budgie 19.10. My partitions are as follows:

- 1 TB HDD as `sda`
- 128 GB SSD as `sdb`

The swap is mounted on `sdb1`, boot is mounted on `sdb2` root `/` is mounted on partition `sdb3`. Whats different is my `/home` which is mounted on `sda2`. My reason for this is because `sda` has a larger space so I can allocate more space to my needs.

Now what's getting me confused is upon opening file manager, the `/home` directory is using `sdb3`'s space. In addition to that, there is a folder partition named `/media/adis/a6a2dc80-c317-4c7f-995f-0a307b12534` which defaulted to `/home`'s folders, but they're not symlinked.

I want to use `/media/adis/a6a2dc80-c317-4c7f-995f-0a307b12534` as my `/home` and not use the current `/home` which is mounted on `sdb3` which is shared with root `/` as well (I can confirm this because `/` and `/home` have the same free space).

[image: List of partitions]

Comment: I don't see any mention of sda3 except in your text, but any directories that weren't given a specific location in your file system table (`/etc/fstab`) will of course be allocated space within / (sdb3).  It appears as if you didn't make an entry for sda2 in your fstab (file system table) either during installation, or afterwards.

Comment: Note:  Don't use /dev/sdxy names in your /etc/fstab entry, use UUID or unique IDs that don't change should you add extra drives, or change BIOS/UEFI settings...  Use `blkid` to get UUID info for your partition(s).

Comment: @guiverc Sorry it was a typo, I have edited it to `sdb3`. Yes I have figured that I needed to add an entry to `/etc/fstab`.